# Stepper motor enable line

Tags: stepper-driver

[image: DRV8834 Circuit connection]I am using DRV8834 IC driver to run the 5v stepper motor. I've managed to run the 5v stepper motor using DRV8834 IC by using a breadboard. But I've found we need 3 pins (Step, Direction and enable) to enable and step the device. I came to know that by making the enable pin to high makes the driver disable where there is no power consumption in the whole system.

But the requirement is only to use 2 pins (step and direction). If I don't control the enable pin via microcontroller then the driver and motor (whole system) consume 50mA. I have to find a solution where the driver and motor shouldn't consume any power until enable line receives the step output pulse from the microcontroller.Also, the step output will always stop in the low state. Is there any idea you can help me with to use any MOSFET/any other idea/pulse stretcher to control the power consumption without using the enable pin? Please let me know if you guys got an idea. Your help is much appreciated.

---

Update to clarify @Transistor's answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG1x1i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) Please add a schematic diagram. If you are using a screenshot then please turn of the grid for legibility. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. (2) "*... motor consume tiny power.*" Please edit your question to make it clear whether tiny power is OK or not. ("Tiny power" should be replaced by a measurement - amps or watts.) (3) Can you guarantee that the step output will always stop in the same state (either high or low)? Put all the information **in your question**.

Comment: Your edit has addressed point (2). What about (1) and (3)? I numbered them so you couldn't forget!

Comment: did you get enough information for you to answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNjAlU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. SLEEP control.*

How it works:

- When STEP goes low D1 discharges C1. Q2 turns off and R2 pulls /SLEEP high enabling the output.
- When STEP stops high C1 charges through R1, Q2 turns on and the stepper goes into sleep mode.
- C1 can only be discharged to about 0.5 V with D1 and that would tend to turn on Q2. Adding D2 prevents this happening (hopefully).

Choose C1 so that R1 x C1 is the time delay you require.

Comment: I believe he may need to use /ENABLE instead of /SLEEP. Page 19 of the [DRV8834 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8834.pdf) indicates that sleep resets the internal logic and "returns the indexer to the home state". Of course that will need a logic inversion.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I have to use /Enable line instead of /Sleep line. Sorry I have mentioned wrong as the step output always stays low. Will this circuit still works?. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, Dhinesh. I answered your original question. You provided incorrect information. You should be able to modify my solution to give the required signal for your new specification. I have shown how to draw the timing waveforms.

Comment: @Dhinesh ... Note that this circuit was designed to your original specification that the step output always stops in the high state. You will need to take that into account and you need to be more careful providing information that is material to the design.

Comment: I am really sorry to both of you. I will be very careful in future. It could be a great help if you could help me with the quick modification I need to do with the original specification. Also could you please tell me what kind of diode can I use? Thanks

Comment: Hit the edit button on my post, hit "edit" on the schematic, select all and press Ctrl-C to copy the lot. Quit the edits. Go to your post and add a schematic. Paste in mine, edit the timing diagram and edot my circuit solution to suit the new timing diagram. We'll comment on your solution. This way you'll learn some design.

Comment: I think I would do that with the DIR line not the step line. You can toggle that all day and the motor wont move. IF you are holding with the stepper motor this circuit will power off after the delay. Toggling DIR would keep it alive without changing motor position. Better still.. use BOTH!

Comment: @Trevor: That's an excellent suggestion. To be more precise - use EITHER rather than both. If either STEP or DIR is toggling then ENABLE. If not then disable after a time.

Comment: YUp throw in an xor

Comment: @Transistor thanks for your help. yes, you are right modifying the schematic myself will help me to learn. I will have to do it myself if the condition I am looking for with the original circuit is wrong. But I have a doubt, this circuit seems like work for me, the condition I am looking for is 1. when the step goes low (default condition), Q2 is off and /enable line is pulled to Vcc (which is high and it doesn't enable the driver) 2.When the step goes high, Q2 goes on and the stepper goes into enable mode. Please correct me if I am wrong.Thanks

Comment: @Trevor thank you so much for your suggestion with too many options.

Comment: @Dhinesh: Draw the modified schematic and timing as requested otherwise we all get confused about which version we are discussing. Note that the ---- bar over SLEEP means that the input is inverted and you must pull it LOW to put it to sleep.

Comment: @Transistor I will do. Please wait

Comment: @Transistor this is the first time I am doing. Please forgive me if it is not to the mark. I just changed the timing diagram. Is that makes sense now? Please let me know

Comment: OK. I moved it down to the bottom and created an update section. (1) Now fix the timing diagram. It's not clear which is the stopped state. Put a piece of text marked PAUSE or IDLE over the timing diagram to show when the /SLEEP or /ENABLE should be off. (2) Clarify your question to say which you are using.

Comment: is that clear now?

Comment: @Transistor Hi the same circuit is working fine for me. Step output is turning on the transistor to enable the motor. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dhinesh: Good work. The important thing is to learn: do you understand how the modification works?

Comment: @transistor I didn't do the modification. I realised NPN transistor is converting the step output to the /enable signal for the motor. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Transistor's answer, this circuit monitors both the DIR and the STEP lines for rising edges and will turn off the sleep signal for a period set by the values or C2 and R3.

R1,C1, R2 act as a high pass filter to turn on Q1 on rising edges of the XOR gate for a short period. This charges C2 down to the ground rail. R3 discharges C2 back up to Vcc. M1 will turn on when the voltage decays back up to Vgs.

Being edge triggered the micro has to actually toggle something to keep it alive. When holding, toggle the DIR line both directions before the RC timer times out. When running the step signal "should" keep it awake naturally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVpH1E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The XOR could be replaced with discrete parts, but take care not to distort the DIR and STEP signals.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution based on the assumption that you can make the micro outputs high impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8a8wg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note each signal line is biased to half rail when the output from the micro is high impedance. These biased signals are then fed to two window comparators in a quad LM339. The biased signals are then compared with 1/3 and 2/3 rail voltages and the outputs orred together with diodes and the pull down. If any of them are outside the gray logic range the sleep signal is deactivated.

Since DIR and STEP change states at different times, there should be no time that both are transitioning through the grey logic area at the same time, so this configuration should work.

This means you can put the driver to sleep just by changing the configuration of the outputs to high impedance.

You could do a similar thing with four opto-couplers if you have the drive for the LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpdspy.png)</sup>