# microcontroller with buttons/LEDs -- fallback when Hi-Z

Tags: microcontroller, led, switches, opto-isolator, button

I'm designing a circuit with a fallback function and would like to know whether it's flawed or can be done with less components.

The MCU here starts a motor in "up" or "down" direction. (Only "up" is shown).

- If the top end switch is touched, then positively, definitely do not go further up.
- The MCU needs to know if the end switch is touched, not only for the sake of stopping.
- The push button is multi-purpose, including the menu navigation and alike.
- However, if the MCU is down (a firmware update went wrong etc.), the push button starts the motor.
- As long as the MCU is running (signalling this fact with a logic "1" at a push-pull output), the push button is solely for the MCU and should not start the motor.

Answering @Bruce Abbott 's question. I had VDD=5V in mind. D1 protects the opto-isolator U1, which might have a [maximum reverse voltage](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) around 5V. Without D2 the BtnUp input would always read "1". Both D1 and D2 could probably be omitted with VDD=3.3V?

D3 is [green or longer wavelength](http://lednique.com/leds-and-colour/) but good that you asked. I ought to count p-n junctions in this path.

R1 and R4 might become MCU's internal pull-down resistors, but they might be too high-ohmic from EMI perspective.

[image: Fallback]

Partially inspired by [this Tri-State post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335717/tri-state-detection) and [lednique.com](http://lednique.com)

Comment: you're right, sorry.

Comment: What is the purpose of the diode across the lower optocoupler? What voltage is Vdd, and what color is the 'going up' LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFTkq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An alternative.*

This might be a little simpler - if I've covered all requirements.

> If the top end switch is touched, then positively, definitely do not go further up.

Satisfied. Opening UP_LS will turn off the opto-LED.

> The MCU needs to know if the end switch is touched, not only for the sake of stopping.

Satisfied. The limit switch monitor [C] will pull high when the switch opens.

> The push button is multi-purpose, including the menu navigation and alike.

Satisfied - maybe. The button monitor [A] will report the state of the switch. During automatic opreation [B] will pull high and V<sub>A</sub> will be equal to the V<sub>F</sub> of D1. If this is a problem another diode in series with R1 and a pull-down on [A] should fix that.

> However, if the MCU is down (a firmware update went wrong etc.), the push button starts the motor.

If the microcontroller is running then [B] should be low which will short out D1. If the micro fails (and the output tri-states) then the UP button will illuminate D1.

> As long as the MCU is running ... the push button is solely for the MCU and should not start the motor.

Satisfied. When [B] is low the LED is short-circuited.

I have deliberately omitted your indication LED for simplicity. Adding it back in affects the V<sub>F</sub> considerations above so the additional diode and pull-down would be required to prevent false button reads on [A].